# How to pass data from terminal in elixir

Tags: terminal, elixir

Hello I want to execute an elixir file and passing one string in my terminal and read it in the script. Something like this:

```
User>elixir script.exs create
```

I want the word "create" to be readed by elixir.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the list of arguments using `System.argv/0`:

```
$ cat a.exs
IO.inspect System.argv
$ elixir a.exs foo bar
["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @RicardoVillagranaLarios Also have a look here https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/OptionParser.html, it may be useful.